# XAML Label Text: Binding + DynamicResource (String Format?)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, dynamicresource

For Xamarin.Forms - XAML files:

is there a way to bind the **Text Property** (in XAML) of a Label to a **Binding + DynamicResource**? Maybe with string format?

for example I tried something like this:

`<Label Text="{DynamicResource resource, Binding binding, StringFormat='Resource: {0} and Binding: {1}"} />`

But one cannot declare a binding if a dynamic resource is set, same problem if trying it vice versa (eg. no dynamicresource if binding already set)

- or with a value converter that returns the binding string to "binding string + dynamic resource"? (Creating a valueconverter for this seems too overwhelming)
- in code this might work with string.Format(...)

Comment: Seems like a job for a converter (`IValueConverter`) to me ...

Comment: Are you implementing it then? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like MultiBinding is not supported in Xamarin.Forms applications.

This is a nice workaround that kind of implements full multibinding support for Xamarin:

http://intellitect.com/multibinding-in-xamarin-forms/

Here is a simpler implementation ready to be used:

https://gist.github.com/Keboo/0d6e42028ea9e4256715

And a discussion about the subject:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21034/multibinding-support

Comment: Thanks alot, 

http://intellitect.com/multibinding-in-xamarin-forms/ looks like a promising way to go. I will investigate on this and update this post, if I get a nice result.

Comment: I added a new link to my answer with a simple ready to use class ;)

Comment: Thanks alot, how will I handle this question now? Tick your answer as correct, or wait for me to update it, as soon as I upload my working solution, and tick my upload then?

Comment: Well, If you think I provided an answer to the question: Is there a way to bind the Text Property (in XAML) of a Label to a Binding + DynamicResource? then mark it as an answer but that's up to you of course.

Comment: You are right. And I can still edit my post to show my solution based on your answer! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is MultiBinding.

Try creating a converter class like this:

```
public class MultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0].ToString() + " " + values[1].ToString();
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Reference it in your App.xaml or other resource dictionary

```
<local:MultiBindingConverter x:Key="MultiBindingConverter" />
```

Then do something like this in your View:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConverter}">
            <Binding Path="FirstProperty" />
            <Binding Path="SecondProperty" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

FirstProperty and SecondProperty are just regular properties in ViewModel.

Comment: This is about Xamarin.Forms, I can't find anything on MultiBinding for Xamarin.Forms. Are u targeting WPF in your example?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice Xamarin tag. Yes, my answer was related to WPF